# C++ - Check if a character is present at a given position on the console

Tags: c++, command-line, position

If I have the coordinates of a point on the screen `x` and `y` and I wanna check if a specified character is at those coordinates on the screen, how do I do it?

I am using Borland C++(for a school project) and the screen is command-line.

Comment: I have done that while taking OS classed by directly accessing the graphics memory.

Comment: Is it Windows console (cmd)?And what type of coordinates?

Comment: @InQusitive Can you show how did you do it?

Comment: Get a pointer to the screen `char *p = mkfar(0xB800:0)`, then `if (p[2 * (x + y * 80)] == 'a') ...` or something like that?

Comment: @It-Z Yes. Mats Peterson, I'll try that.

Comment: @DhruvRamani: Mats answer looks similar to what I did. B8000 is the address of the graphics buffer.

Comment: @InQusitive Okay, I'll try it. Can't try it now though, don't have access to my Windows PC.

Comment: Actually, it depends on whether it's a "colour" or "monochrome" graphics adapter, but since this is probably running in a dos-box on 32-bit Windows, it would be using CGA combatibility.

Comment: There is no language C/C++.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Do I require a header file to use the mkfar() function? Sorry, I am a noob in C++.

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones, you will get help from here and it is independent of the platform

Comment: Given that I was programming in text-mode and poking at the screen last time something like 14 years ago, and that was in 32-bit mode [running a real-time OS in 32-bit mode, so I just set the pointer to 0xB8000], I think I can be excused not remembering...

Comment: MatsPeterson its fine! @InQusitive Can you tell me more about the mkfar() , I can't seem to find info. about it anywhere.

Comment: Upon a little research I found out that I need to use `MK_FP` defined in dos.h .But for Borland compilers, `#define MK_FP(seg,off) (((seg)<<16)|(off)) `. @MatsPetersson will this work?

Comment: With that you could (i believe) actually just use char p = MK_FP(0xB8000, 2 * (x+y*80)) to get the address of the space on the screen you're looking for. then just *p ==  'a' to check it's value. FYI, MK_FP is make far pointer, it's make an address pointer to a locations not relative to your code in the format of segment:offset. I think of segment as the base of the block of memory, and offset as the offset into that block. It's more complicated than that. but that's the gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I avoided the use of this in my program, and came up with a better solution to the odd problem, this seemed to work :

```
#include <windows.h>

//....

 char get_char_at_xy( int x, int y )
  {
   CHAR_INFO ci;
   COORD xy = { 0, 0 };
   SMALL_RECT rect = { x, y, x, y };
   return ReadConsoleOutput(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),&ci,1,xy,rect)
       ? ci.Char.AsciiChar
       : '\0';
  }
```